# CSS works locally but not on server

Tags: css, wordpress, position, media-queries

Please go to [containmydog.com](http://containmydog.com) in mobile view, and click the menu - you will see a phone number shows up - when you close the menu the number disappears. The phone number is not supposed to disappear, and it doesn't do this on my local version of the site. The phone number has a fixed position and should be visible regardless of whether the menu is open or closed.

This is the css I have (which you can see for yourself in the browser):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .cmd-nav .phone-no a {
        font-size: 20px;
        background: none;
    }

    .cmd-nav .phone-no {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    position: fixed;
    top: -5px;
    left: 96px;
    border: none;
    background: url(//localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/containmydog/css/../images/phone-icon.png) no-repeat left 8px top 8px;
    }
}
```

Why does the number not appear initially? Why does it disappear after closing the menu?

Answer (score 0):

The element that contains the phone number is nested inside of the `#nav-collapse-primary` div, which has the `collapse` class. When the box is collapsed, everything inside of that div is hidden. Try putting the phone number inside `#navbar-header` or some other div that doesn't get hidden instead.